# Trouble Floating Divs Correctly

Tags: css, html, css-float

My divs are displaying a staircase effect, as shown below. Usually in tables you can use `vertical-align: top`, not sure how to do this for divs.

```
 ____1_____     
            _____2_____      
                        ______3_____
```

The CSS I have so far is:

```
   .areadiv
{
float:left;
display: inline-block;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto; 
width:130px;
padding:5px;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div>
<div class="areadiv">
content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pZEau/  ????

Comment: sorry, it is <div><div class="areadiv">content</div></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS doesn't make so much sense with the layout you're are trying to achieve, it should be:

```
.areadiv {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

The `margin: 0 auto;` is used for centering container divs and you don't need the inline-block.

Comment: I had tried that but no change. I added the margin and height after I tried that

Comment: Please post your HTML, you seem to want 3 divs that sit next to each other, so you need to have at least 3 times `<div class="areadiv">`

Comment: there is only three divs right now but there will eventually be more than three. the divs are states, then under the states are cities. so eventually there will be 50 divs total on the page. not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @bartolsthoorn that your CSS is quite confusing. But rather than using float I'd use only `display: inline-block`. And when you use `inline-block` you have to remember to set `vertical-align` as well as most (all?) browsers default to `middle`:

```
.areadiv {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

That's all you need.

Comment: If you do this, you need to set display:inline for IE7 and lower, if you support them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok firstly the width of the containing div must be set = or > than the combined widths of the floats, that's how it knows to move on to the next line.

For example..

```
.areadiv 
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.containerdiv 
{
    width: 421px; /* ( 130 + 10 ) x 3 + 1 just in case */
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="containerdiv">
    <div class="areadiv">
    </div>
    <div class="areadiv">
    </div>
    <div class="areadiv">
    </div>
</div>
```